# Opencv 3 install directory name

Tags: opencv

I just built opencv version 3.3.1 from source and I'm trying to link the libraries in a CMakeLists.txt file. In order to do that I need to know the install location.

It looks like I found it to be located at `/usr/local/include`. What is throwing me off is there are two "opencv" titled folders in this directory, one is name open "opencv" the other is named "opencv2". However there is no "opencv3" folder, but when I run `$opencv_version` in my terminal I get output "3.3.1-dev". So I know I've successfully installed opencv version 3, however I don't see a similarly named directory.

When looking at my make install output I see lines like:

`Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.3.4.1
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.3.4`

so it looks like I'm installing opencv version 3 with a directory named "opencv2". Did the engineers who made opencv version 3 really name their install directory opencv2???

I just would like confirmation to make sure I'm not crazy.

Comment: yes they did .... and in python is cv2... a little bit crazy, but... it is like that. Not sure why they did not have cv3 or opencv3... but I think in 4.x it will be the same :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

I set the install directory for opencv in my make file as "/usr/local/include/opencv2" and the library was found. Also thanks to [api55](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888688/api55) for confirming my suspensions.